# Cannot retrieve items from array? [AHK]

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to improve my AHK skills by making random, silly programs that use different concepts in different ways. Right now, I'm making a code breaking program for Rust, a steam game. My code is listed below, but it doesn't seem to enter the code properly. Most of the code is within `enterCode()`, so that I can call it say, 20 times, without having to write each `MouseClick` statement a million times. Only problem is, `if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = x)` doesn't seem to be working correctly. Am I not passing the function parameters into the array correctly? It performs the first section correctly, and then does nothing after that, so there isn't any error I can look at. My only guess is that nothing is getting put into the array, but I've looked at many other example programs and this seems right. (Also, the last two lines of my code aren't merging with the rest, but they are both in the same program.)

```
enterCode(number1, number2, number3, number4)
{
codeArray=:[] ;define the array, with nothing in it
codeArray[1]:=number1 ;enumerate passed parameters into array for loop
codeArray[2]:=number2
codeArray[3]:=number3
codeArray[4]:=number4

sleep 100
send {e down} ;open door context menu
sleep 200
MouseClick, left, 942, 536 ;click to open code interface
sleep 500
send {e up}
sleep 200

loop, 4
{       
    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 0) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 1) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 2) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 3) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 4) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 5) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 6) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 7) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 8) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }

    if (codeArray[%A_Index%] = 9) 
    {
        MouseClick, left, 1217, 668
        continue
    }                                                                       
}
```

}

```
F3::
enterCode(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
codeArray=:[] ;define the array, with nothing in it
```

To this:

```
codeArray := []
```

Comment: I'm curious why adding whitespace would fix the issue.

Comment: It doesn't. Changing the typo `=:` to `:=` fixes it.  The white space helps to distinguish the assignment operator